# postID collection? through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've spent last days trying to get a list of recent comments in my site with no success

What I want to retrieve is just **the same content as I can get at**
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id={APP_ID}&view=recent_comments](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=%7BAPP_ID%7D&view=recent_comments)

For example...
[https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID}/comments](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BAPP_ID%7D/comments)

Always returns...

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I've read this query should be made to a `post_id`, not `app_id`, but then...
How can I get a collection of `postID`s made in my site??

Can you someone give me a tip?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [Comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):

> How do I access the comments left on my site?
>
> The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.

There's also a sample URL that shows the return type and a link to some sample code

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but that method is valid for one specific URL. And that's just my problem, cause comments can be placed in multiple (and dynamic) URLs. So the intention remains to retrieve the comments for the whole site, as I've said, just the same content I can see at [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id={APP_ID}&view=recent_comments) Browsing there I can see a collection of all comments, I want to believe there's a way to do that through the Graph API

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you should be able to pass multiple URLs in a single request, and you'll already know all the URLs that could possibly have comments because they're on your own site, could be a usable workaround